# How can I use a variable as an operator?

Tags: php, html

I would like code 1 to work the same as code 2, but it doesn't.

```
<?php
//code 1
$z = '>';
$v = 50;
$a1[0] = 60;

if($v .$z. $a1[0])
{
    echo "<td>" . "test" . "</td>";
} else {}

//code 2
if($v > $a1[0]){
    echo "<td>" . "test" . "</td>";
} else {}
```

In the above code I want to replace the > symbol with a variable so that I can make it dynamic.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just don't...do not do that...you can use something like `eval`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php , but read the caution note.

Comment: I have checked and it seemed it would be diffucult to implment in my logic any other way@Hackerman

Comment: Can you post what your actual use-case is? This doesn't seem like a sensible solution to any problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot iainn.. The below answer works perfect

Comment: Why? I've seen this in attempts to make calculators etc. but why would you want to use a variable for a "greater than" check in your serverside code?

Comment: Although I did answer, I agree it seems like kind of an odd thing to try to do. I'm also curious what you're doing with it.

Comment: Thanks Adeneo.. I am moderate in php, so I will study on eval() but the below answer given by @dont Panic guy worked. thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, *you can't* use a variable as an operator in PHP.

All that the `$v .$z. $a1[0]` expression does is concatenate the variables together into a string.

I think the closest you'd be able to get to being able to use a "dynamic operator" would be to define an array of operations that you could select from using your variable.

```
$ops = [
    '>' => function($a, $b) { return $a > $b; },
    '<' => function($a, $b) { return $a < $b; },
    '=' => function($a, $b) { return $a == $b; }
];

$z = '>';

$v = 50;

$a1[0] = 60;

if ($ops[$z]($v, $a1[0])) {
    echo "<td>" . "test" . "</td>";
}
```

(Keep in mind that with your example values, `$v` is *not* greater than `$a1[0]`, so this example won't echo anything.)

---

Regarding `eval`, since it was mentioned a couple of times in the comments on your question, most people advise against using it, for good reasons. There is almost always a better way to solve your problem.